# Plesk Migrator Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)

Tags: centos, ssh, plesk, cpanel

I'm trying to use Plesk Migrator to transfer data from a cpanel server. I'm using the command line version however I'm receiving an error I can't seem to fix. The same error also shows from Plesk's migrator GUI.

```
Failed to connect to the the source server 'cpanel' (remote-host-ip) at 'remote-host-ip' by SSH as 'remote-host-user': Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)
```

I've got my sshd_config setup like this,

```
MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
Ciphers 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
```

and can connect to the Cpanel Server with the normal SSH command absolutely fine using the private key, so it's escaping me why this is happening on the migrator!

Edit: Just to let you know I also have no control over the cPanel server as it's with a generic hosting provider - as said though, SSH'ing in from the Plesk server works a-okay with it.

Comment: All control panel are offtopic here, because the questions about them were very LQ. I don't really like this rule (in my opinion, their LQ majority should be closed as LQ, the others are ontopic), but my opinion is in minority.

Answer (score 2):

Set the following in sshd_config:

```
Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

Or just comment them and migration should work.

Comment: I've set my sshd_config exactly like that, but unfortunately it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Try to comment them than. Can you share what is in sshd_config on source server?

Comment: This is the entire sshd_config on the plesk server, don't have access to the one on the cPanel server.
https://pastebin.com/6umiwZWV

Comment: Did to you try to remove (comment) ciphers, macs and kex from sshd_config on target server at all?